# CSV reader object not reading entire file [Python]

Tags: python, csv

I am currently working on a project that uses the csv module in python.  I have created a separate class to open a pre-existing csv file, modify the data on each line, then save the data to a new csv file.

The original file has 1438 rows, and by placing some test code into the class that handles the writing, it indicates that it is writing 1438 rows to the new csv file.  Upon inspection of the file itself, there is infact 1438 rows in the newly created file.  However, when I use the standard cvs module in this way:

```
reader = csv.reader(open('naiveData.csv', 'rb'))
```

It only goes to row 1410 (and not even then entire row, it ends one and a half indices before the end of the row.  I am not sure what may be causing this.

This is how I am accessing the reader:

```
 for row in reader:                                                          
    print row
```

Here is the part of the output where it fails:

```
['UNPM', '16', '2.125', '910', 'athlete', 'enrolled'] 
['UNPM', '14', '2.357', '1020', 'non-athlete', 'enrolled']    
['UNDC', '17', '2.071', '910', 'athlete', 'unenrolled']  
['KINS', '15', '2.6', '910', 'athlete', 'enrolled']  
['PHYS', '16', '1.5', '900', 'non-']
```

The last list should have ['PHYS', '16', '1.5', '900', 'non-athlete', 'enrolled'].

Any ideas as to what may be causing this?  Thanks in advance!

**Edit:**

Here are the lines in the CVS file around the area the error is occuring:

```
KINS,15,2.6,910,athlete,enrolled
PHYS,16,1.5,900,non-athlete,enrolled
UNPL,15,3,960,non-athlete,enrolled
```

Comment: Can you post the full line from the input file where the output breaks?

Comment: @PedroWerneck sure thing, I added it at the bottom of the question

Comment: So you're doing read_csv(x) -> process -> write_csv(y), then when you read_csv(y) again to read the rows, some are missing?

Comment: It looks like the file wasn't completely flushed to disk when you read. Are you using the with statement? Did you close it properly after writing to it?

Comment: When you write the file, do you explicitly call `.close()` or are you using a `with` statement to make sure the file is properly closed?  I'm wondering if the file is not being fully written somehow before your writing program terminates.  If you are using CPython this doesn't seem likely, but if you are using Jython or PyPy it seems possible.

Comment: @steveha: IIRC, Jython guarantees that all open files will be flushed at normal program shutdown, while CPython explicitly says it's not guaranteed, so you've got that backward. But either way, if he's able to see the complete file after the program has finished, it must have gotten flushed at some point, so the problem must be something else. (My answer is a guess at that something else, based on something I've seen a lot of novices do, but it's probably not the only possibility.)

Comment: @abarnert, clearly you know more than I do about these details.  Does CPython actually take the trouble to garbage-collect alive objects at program termination?  I thought it did, but if it doesn't guarantee files will be closed that sounds like it doesn't.  How about Jython, does it GC all objects at termination, or does it treat open files as a special case, or what?  (I never play games with this stuff; I just use `with` so I don't know the fine points of what you can get away with and what you can't.)

Comment: @steveha: I believe Jython treats files as a special case, because the JVM gives it a way to do so for free, but that's just a vague memory/guess. As for CPython… If you're asking what it _does_ rather than what it _guarantees_, that's a lot harder. I'll get to that, but I'm pretty sure what it _guarantees_ is that objects may or may not be finalized, and files may or may not be flushed and you aren't allowed to rely on either, and that's it.

Comment: @steveha: Meanwhile, CPython _tries_ to delete everything at termination time, by using a sequence of `gc.collect` calls and explicit deletions of specific things like modules. If often doesn't get everything. I think 3.1 improved the sequence, and 3.4's finalizer logic should automatically make the existing logic work better, but I'm sure it still won't be perfect. If a file object doesn't get closed, in 2.x the buffers are usually owned by stdio, and it's up to your platform's rules whether they get flushed; in 3.x, they're owned by Python `io` objects, and get dropped.

Comment: @steveha: I'm willing to bet that I got at least one major piece of that wrong, of course. :)

Comment: Thank you for writing all that!  I guess the real wild card is Pypy, which I believe guarantees nothing.  In any event, the moral of the story is to always use `with` and get boringly safe and predictable file closings. :-)

Comment: http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2009/06/12/safely-using-destructors-in-python/  CPython did call the `.__del__()` methods on his objects when the program terminated.  However, when he made a cycle of references, neither object's `.__del__()` was called.  So for CPython, it is probably safe to assume that program termination will result in open file objects being closed as they are closed before termination, *unless* you involve a file object in a cycle of object references.  So my prediction about CPython behavior was probably about right.  But nobody should rely on that; use `with`!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm willing to bet this is the problem, although it's hard to be sure when you've only shown us 3 lines of code instead of a reproducible example.

You're doing something like this:

```
old_reader = csv.reader(open('old.csv', 'rb'))
writer = csv.writer(open('new.csv', 'wb'))
for row in old_reader:
    writer.writerow(transform(row))
new_reader = csv.reader(open('new.csv', 'rb'))
for row in new_reader:
    print row
```

At the time you open `new.csv` for reading, you haven't yet closed `new.csv` for writing. So the last buffer hasn't been flushed to disk. So you can't see it.

But then, when your script finishes, the `writer` goes out of scope, the file object no longer has any references, so it gets flushed and closed. So when you inspect it from outside of the program, after the script finishes, now it's complete. (Note that this behavior is explicitly not guaranteed; you're just getting lucky.)

And this is why you should never leak files by just putting an `open` in the middle of an expression. Use a `with` statement instead. For example:

```
with open('old.csv', 'rb') as oldf, open('new.csv', 'wb') as newf:
    old_reader = csv.reader(oldf)
    writer = csv.writer(newt)
    for row in old_reader:
        writer.writerow(transform(row))
with open('new.csv', 'rb') as newf:
    new_reader = csv.reader(newf)
    for row in new_reader:
        print row
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this explanation!  It worked perfectly.  I will keep the concept of using a with statement in mind next time.

Comment: This happened to me also through subprocess.Popen, having a process generating the csv file. Replacing the Popen() call by run() solved this (python 3.5.2)

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue, but eventually the problem was that a comma was missing in a row of the csv file