# Trouble returning the entire CSV data frame

Tags: python, pandas, return

When I run the code below, I am only getting the first row (my name row) of my CSV file. What can I do to make sure the code below returns my entire CSV?

```
import csv 
import pandas as pd

import numpy as np

def open_elves():

    with open('elves.csv') as csvjawn:
        readCS = csv.reader(csvjawn, delimiter = ',')
        for row in readCS:
            return row                
x = pd.DataFrame(open_elves())

print (x)
```

Answer (score 5):

## Use the `read_csv` function provided by the Pandas api

```
df = pd.read_csv('elves.csv')
```

Answer (score 3):

Return always quits the loop immediately. Try e.g.

```
def f():
    for i in range(100):
        return i

f()
```

What your flow should look like instead is something like:

```
with open('elves.csv') as csvjawn:
    readCS = csv.reader(csvjawn, delimiter = ',')
    data = [row for row in readCS]
```

This uses a list comprehension which you may want to research if you haven't seen before.

Answer (score -1):

I wouldn't use `return` to accomplish what you want to do.

The response of stackoverflow's colleague (abarnert):

```
with open('old.csv', 'rb') as oldf, open('new.csv', 'wb') as newf:
    old_reader = csv.reader(oldf)
    writer = csv.writer(newt)
    for row in old_reader:
        writer.writerow(transform(row))
with open('new.csv', 'rb') as newf:
    new_reader = csv.reader(newf)
    for row in new_reader:
        print row
```

url: [CSV reader object not reading entire file [Python]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19942308/csv-reader-object-not-reading-entire-file-python)